# How to fix 0x80071A91 error in Windows Vista / backup Vista system?

Tags: windows-vista, backup

I am getting this error below:

> "File backup could not save your automatic backup settings for the following reason:
>
> Transaction support within the specified file system resource manager is not started or was shutdown due to an error. (0x80071A91)
>
> Please try again."

I tryed this (to fix) on cmd:

> “fsutil resource setautoreset true C:\” as an adm

But did not work.

What I want is to make a backup of all my files.

Answer (score 1):

Did you delete all files first from `C:\Windows\System32\config\TxR` before executing fsutil? Make sure explorer shows system and hidden files.

Comment: +1: I gave you that tip on Channel 9, you had the same issue with an update.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yup, I'm passing on the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

John [see this blog post](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/alexark/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=5)

> Recently I was very frustrated installing Vista on my home machine. It’s not that something wrong with Vista, it was drivers that drove me crazy. Problems I had were caused by the fact that nVidia failed to provide working drivers for RAID 0+1 array based on nForce 4 Ultra chipset (I’ve got ASUS A8N-E motherboard). When I finally managed to install everything, it was running fine for couple of weeks. After certain point though Windows updates begun to fail as well as Vista backup feature stopped working. I had basically only one clue. It’s an error message I was getting when I tried to start a backup job:
>
> File backup could not save your automatic backup settings for the following reason:
>
> Transaction support within the specified file system resource manager is not started or was shutdown due to an error. (0x80071A91)
>
> Please try again.
>
> Microsoft help wasn’t really helpful: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927748/en-us. Googling didn’t bring any luck either, so I start researching toward file system resource manager (FSRM). Accidently I found that fsutil tool has an additional argument “resource”, which evidently controls FSRM behavior.
>
> So, if you see a bunch of failed Windows Updates and/or your Vista files backup doesn’t work anymore, here are the steps you need to do in order to reset FSRM:
>
> Click “WinKey” on your keyboard.
> Type “cmd” and hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter. That will bring you to the command prompt in Administrator mode. It you still have UAC enabled, it will ask you for permissions, click “OK”.
> Navigate to your Vista system folder (i.e. C:\Windows\System32)
> Type “fsutil resource setautoreset true C:\” assuming that you have your Vista on drive C.
> Reboot.